# json validation for Mongodb query

Tags: json, mongodb

I am using following JSON in my MongoDB query but it is failing in JSON parser. Can anyone let me know what is incorrect in the below query?

```
{"lastProcessedTime":{$gte: new Date('2017-08-21T19:59:59.000Z')}}
```

Comment: Your JSON is fine and a valid MongoDB filter. What's the exact error message and how does the rest of your code look? Is that really the place in your code where you get the error?

Comment: My json was failing in json validator https://jsonlint.com/ and I still don't know why. But the real issue was that I was trying to use above json in mongoexport command and it was giving me error. However, I made it work by enclosing the json query in single quotes and it worked.

Comment: This command worked for me - mongoexport -h <server name>:<port> -u <userid> -p <password> --db <database name> --collection <collection name> --type=csv --fields column1,column2,column3,column4,column5 --query '{"lastProcessedTime":{$gte: new Date("2017-08-21T19:59:59.000Z")}}' --out <path>\<file name>.csv